# MODIS image reprojection/ change coordinate system in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-9.3, erdas-imagine, modis

I have downloaded Utah state shapefile in `NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N` projection and also downloaded the MODIS image of the area (MOD09Q1) in .hdf format which has `sinusoidal projection`.

the .hdf format was converted to .img using ERDAS imagine 2011.

Upon adding these two layers in ArcGIS 9.3, the boundary shapefile does not fall on the image rather lies far away. I have also tried projecting the image to NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N...its still not working.

Any suggestion on what to do?

Comment: show us both files properties. In ArcMap, right click over each file, Properties - > Source (for the shapefile) and Properties - > Source -> scroll down until you can see both extent and coordinate system .

Comment: @A. R Utah shape file properties:                                                     Data Type: Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile: G:\THESIS\soil moisture\MODIS\Utah_shp\Utah\Utah.shp
Geometry Type: Polygon

Projected Coordinate System: NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian: -111.00000000
Scale_Factor: 0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.00000000
Linear Unit:  Meter

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: Check out http://code.env.duke.edu/projects/mget/wiki/SinusoidalMODIS the instructions are mainly to get data into the MODIS coordinate system, but you may be able to reverse the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to ENVI, there is a a "MODIS conversion toolkit" available for free from their user scripts website.

It will reproject any way you would like as well as destripe and calculate radiance

have fun

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try working with MODIS hdf files entirely in ArcGIS using [Extract Subdataset](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Extract_Subdataset_%28Data_Management%29), [Project Raster](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Project_Raster_%28Data_Management%29), and then either [Clip](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Clip_%28Data_Management%29) the raster or [Extract by Mask](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Extract_by_Mask) to subset to your Utah boundary.

Comment: thnks..the Extract Subdataset tool is not being run, unexpected error is shown. Also when .hdf file is added into ArcGIS 9.3 the extension becomes .hdf:0. Is this the reason for error?

Comment: My ArcGIS 10.1 is working fine, so I am unable to reproduce the error you are experiencing in 9.3, but others have also experienced and documented here (with a link to a helpful tool): [Converting HDFs to ArcGIS Rasters](http://code.env.duke.edu/projects/mget/wiki/Converting%20HDFs%20to%20ArcGIS%20rasters). This may also be helpful to you: [Batch Processing 400 MODIS HDF4 Files Using Several Tools In ArcGIS 10](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17613/batch-processing-400-modis-hdf4-files-using-several-tools-in-arcgis-10)

Comment: One other thing: do you have all MODIS tiles that cover Utah? The [MODIS tiles shapefile from here](http://gis.fem-environment.eu/modis-sinusoidal-gis-files/) show three tiles: h08v05, h09v04, h09v05.

Comment: no, i don't have all the three tiles only h09v05. thnks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Using MODIS REPROJECTION TOOL WEB INTERFACE (MRTWEB) i was able to convert the .hdf files to .tiff format and reproject to geographic coordinate system. The boundary shapefile was also given geographic coordinate system and the boundary fell correctly over the image in ArcGIS9.3